# how to handle transactions in WCF services

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WPF application and In button click event I am calling WCF service for handling transaction in it. After one transaction complete I am throwing exception. To see whether transaction will rollback or not. But even I got error still transaction got completed it is not aborted in database.

**UI Button event:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    binding = new WSHttpBinding();
    endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:6144/EmployeeService.svc/EmployeeService");

    ChannelFactory<IEmployeeService> cf = new ChannelFactory<IEmployeeService>(binding, endpoint);
    IEmployeeService obj = cf.CreateChannel();

    using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
    {
        try
        {
            obj.UpdateProductData(201, 10);
            throw new Exception("Wrong");
            obj.UpdateProductData(202, 15);
            ts.Complete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ts.Dispose();                          
        }
    }
}
```

In app.config i already given `"transactionFlow="true"`.

**WCF Service:**

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired=true,TransactionAutoComplete=true)]
public bool UpdateProductData(int ProdId, int Amount)
{
    DALClass objDALProd = new DALClass();
    return objDALProd.UpdateProductData(ProdId, Amount);
}
```

**DALClass:**

```
public bool UpdateProductData(int prodID,int Amount)
{
    try
    {
        objComd.Connection = objConn;
        objConn.Open();
        objComd.CommandText = "UpdateEmployeeData";
        objComd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        objParam = new SqlParameter("@ProductId", prodID);
        objComd.Parameters.Add(objParam);
        objParam = new SqlParameter("@Amount", Amount);
        objComd.Parameters.Add(objParam);

        objComd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        objConn.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new FaultException("Database Error");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Please let me know where my mistake is. Transaction is not rolled back, even when I am raising exception first transaction is not rolled back.

Comment: Note: you don't need the `try/catch/ts.Dispose()` part. That's what the `using` block itself is for. Worse yet, you swallow all exceptions there.

Comment: try TransactionAutoComplete=false...

Answer (score 2):

Have you defined the transaction flow on your WCF contract?

```
[OperationContract]
[TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Mandatory)]
```

Have you defined the transaction flow on both the client and server config?

```
<wsHttpBinding>
<binding name="transactionalWsatHttpBinding"
         transactionFlow="true" />
</wsHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Below is the code added for the WCF Contract But no use... please let me know if there is any other way :    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired=true,TransactionAutoComplete=true)] public bool UpdateProductData(int ProdId, int Amount) { DALClass objDALProd = new DALClass(); return objDALProd.UpdateProductData(ProdId, Amount); }

Comment: It looks like you put the attribute on the class not the interface

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to enable transactions in both the client and service binding by setting [WSHttpBindingBase.TransactionFlow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpbindingbase.transactionflow.aspx)=true.
2. You can check on the service being called if the transaction really is flowing by checking if  `Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.DistributedIdentifier` is non-zero. If its zero, then the flow is not working and rollback won't happed.

See the answer to [How can I implement WCF Transaction support on custom class using CoreService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398027/how-can-i-implement-wcf-transaction-support-on-custom-class-using-coreservice/12411868#12411868) for more details and links.

Answer (score 1):

Your client side code looks fine to me, but on the server side, there are a total of 3 attributes you need to get this to work.

Service Interface needs [TransactionFlow] on the operation.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
  [OperationContract]
  [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
  bool UpdateProductData(int ProdId, int Amount);
}
```

Service Class needs [ServiceBehavior] on the class and [OperationBehavior] on the method:

```
[ServiceBehavior(TransactionIsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted)]
public class Service : IService
{
  [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired=true,TransactionAutoComplete=true)]
  public bool UpdateProductData(int ProdId, int Amount)
  {
    DALClass objDALProd = new DALClass();
    return objDALProd.UpdateProductData(ProdId, Amount);
  }
}
```

Also note that these attributes are only one way to do achieve this - you can also do all of this in the config file if desired.  Config files make it easier to apply these settings to multiple services in one shot.